# How to dynamically resize rectangle from bottom to top. Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, drawing, japplet

So I am trying to make a Applet that uses two JSliders to resize a rectangle. I would like to have the height to go from bottom to top to match with what a Vertical JSlider looks like.

The only problem I am running into is that to draw in Java the drawing is from x & y which are both located at 0, moving x left(West), and y is going south. Resizing the width is simple since I am just using a method with a single parameter to increase or decrease width. With height, moving it up is fine (I have y set at 340 since that is the base I'd like to stay at). When I move the JSlider down, it moves down but will not reach the same height it was once at. I would really like to make is seem like the rectangle is moving the same way the JSlider is moving.

Main Applet Page (Where the JSliders are located):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;


public class ResizeRectangle extends JApplet {
    private JSlider sliderHeight;
    private JSlider sliderWidth;
    private JLabel title;
    private Contents content;
    private int oldValue = 0;
    public void init(){

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        title = new JLabel("Rectangle Resizer");
        content = new Contents();

        content.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        //Slider for increasing the height
        sliderHeight = new JSlider(SwingConstants.VERTICAL, 10, 100, 10);
        sliderHeight.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
        sliderHeight.setPaintTicks(true);

        sliderHeight.addChangeListener(
                new ChangeListener(){
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e){
                        //If sliderHeight is greater than oldValue pass true for increase
                        if(sliderHeight.getValue() > oldValue){
                            content.setHeight(sliderHeight.getValue(), true);
                        }
                        //Else if sliderHeight is less than oldValue pass false for increase
                        else if(sliderHeight.getValue() < oldValue){
                            content.setHeight(sliderHeight.getValue(), false);
                        }
                        //Sets the value of sliderHeight to the value of oldValue to compare later
                        oldValue = sliderHeight.getValue();
                    }
                }
        );
        //Slider for increasing the widht
        sliderWidth = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 10, 100, 10);
        sliderWidth.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
        sliderWidth.setPaintTicks(true);

        sliderWidth.addChangeListener(
                new ChangeListener(){
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e){
                        content.setWidth(sliderWidth.getValue());
                    }
                }
        );

        content.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(sliderWidth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(sliderHeight, BorderLayout.EAST);

    }
}
```

This is the code for setting the height (as well as width):

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;



public class Contents extends Component {

    private int height = 10;
    private int width = 10;
    //Initialize y to 340.
    private int y = 340;

    //Draw the rectangle
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.fillRect(5, y, width, height);
    }

    public void setHeight(int h, boolean increase){
        //If the slider is increasing, decrease y and increase height to give it the
        // look of rising 
        if(increase){
            y = y - h;
            height = height + h;
        }
        //else do the opposite
        else{
            y = y + h;
            height = height - h;
        }
        //For debugging purposes
        System.out.println("h = "+h);
        System.out.println("y = "+y);
        System.out.println("height = "+height+"\n\n");
        //Repaint the rectangle
        repaint();

    }
    //Set the width and repaint
    public void setWidth(int w){
        width = w;
        repaint();
    }
}
```

This is my third month of learning Java and I would greatly appreciate any feedback. Thank you in advance.

Comment: *"This is my third month of learning Java"*  I've been using Java since 1999, and am still learning.  :)

Comment: `extends Component`  ... `public void paint(Graphics g){`  ***No!***  For Swing, use `extends JComponent` & `public void paintComponent(Graphics g){`

Comment: @Andrew Thompson everything depends of genetic incident, diligence and commitment, but 13t. years

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks, could you recommend any reading on when to use what kind of Java Component when and where? I've read a good bit from the Oracle website, it's just a large bit of information to grasp.

Comment: Use Swing.  For a quick overview, see [A Visual Guide to Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/features/components.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a logic issue with your code. The call used to change the height inside the change listener is

```
content.setHeight(sliderHeight.getValue(), ...);
```

which looks reasonable on first sight. However the method `setHeight` does not do what the name suggest (i.e. setting the hight) but instead increases or decreases the height by the amount given as first argument:

```
if(increase){
    y = y - h;
    height = height + h;
} else {
    y = y + h;
    height = height - h;
}
```

Thus if the slider changes from 10 to 20 and back to 10 you have the following change of values:

```
// initial values
y = 340
height = 10     

// change from 10 to 20, thus h=20 and increase as arguments for the method
y -> 340 - 20 = 320
height -> 10 + 20 = 30


// change from 20 back to 10, i.e. h=10 and decrease
y -> 320 + 10 = 330
height -> 30 - 10 = 20
```

What the method should do instead is indeed set the height, i.e.

```
y = 340 - h;
height = h;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was extremely confused on how to convey what I wanted in logic, but this helped a ton. I've updated the code to no longer include the booleans in content.setHeight() and just use h for a parameter. Your code example made everything just click.